# How do I get input from an alert?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, alert

I am trying to take input from an alert, but when I try to assign it, it gives me a button alert.

```js
x = alert('Enter: ');
alert(x);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `prompt` instead of `alert` in your code.

Syntax:

> *window.prompt("sometext","defaultText");*

---

```js
x = prompt("Enter text")
alert(x);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  </html>
```

Also, try a google search (e.g. "alert input") and the first option will give you your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`alert` doesn't allow for input, but `prompt` does.

```js
var username = prompt("Enter name", "");

if (username != null) {
    alert("Welcome " + username + "!");
}
```